# How to start and stop client side change in webbrowser control C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I am making an application in which i used WebBrowser Control of .net. But I am facing some problem. I need to to stop and start client side change in browser. Like in some website some data is hidden and when we click data will be shown. But I want to stop and start that event. How can I do this, any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

U can use jQuery for that
**For Canceling Server Side event**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(#ControlID).click(function () {
//WRITE YOUR CODE OR CONDITION TO EXECUTE
          return false;
   });
});
```

**For enabling Server Side event**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(#ControlID).click(function () {
//WRITE YOUR CODE OR CONDITION TO EXECUTE.
          return true; //or
          __doPostBack(#ControlID,'OnClick');
   });
});
```